# In May, my professor agreed to write me letter of recommendation, but now I just graduated

Tags: masters, application, professorship, recommendation-letter

I just graduated recently in May, and right before graduation, I asked if my professors could write me LOR for grad school. And they all agreed. Now I'm in the process of applying to grad schools, but it's almost October, and how should I write the email to remind my professors of LOR? Should I start by asking if their offers still stand, and if they need anything else (like supporting materials) from me?

Answer (score 5):

1. Be friendly, normal, polite, and human and remember that your professors are (or at least should be) too.
2. If they offered to write the LORs, they want to help you out. It makes people feel good to help others especially with LORs, because you get to help someone *and* feel nice and authoritative.
3. I wouldn't even bother asking if the offer still stands. Just make sure that you tell them that you're grateful and appreciative that they made the offer, let them know if there are any deadlines that you have coming up which make the need for LORs more urgent, and you should be just fine.
4. Always offer supplemental documentation if they need it.

Answer (score 2):

You may do that.  However, from May to October is not a very long time, so you could probably omit asking if the offer still stands.  (But I suppose it doesn't do any harm.)

You can always include an unofficial transcript as an attachment.  If they don't need that, they can ignore the attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Send them a polite email as a reminder. Professors are busy people so most of the time they forget about the LOR thing. In the email, first introduce yourself and mention which classes of the Professor you attended, tell him that you enjoyed this and that thing in their class due to which he is the best person to write you an LOR. Attach your CV and ask him if he needs other documents.